# PeerJS not return remote stream

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, peerjs

I doing android webRTC with PeerJS.
Everything working good on Local stream display, send and receive on call response both work.

But have rarely to success connection.
Most result is blank on remote display (Both user).
I don't get any error from logcat and why connection is success just sometime.
That why I don't know to resolve this.

Please give some advice.

//Kotlin Activity//

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_call)

    first = true

    type = intent.getIntExtra("type", -1)
    qUID = intent.getStringExtra("qUID")

    setupWebView()
}

fun onPeerConnected() {
    isPeerConnected = true
    listenForConnId()
}

private fun setupWebView() {
    webView.webChromeClient = object: WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onPermissionRequest(request: PermissionRequest?) {
            request?.grant(request.resources)
        }

        override fun onConsoleMessage(message: ConsoleMessage): Boolean {
            Log.e("PeerJS", "${message.message()} >> From line:" +
                    "${message.lineNumber()} /// ID:${message.sourceId()}")
            return true
        }
    }

    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(JavascriptInterface(this), "Android")

    loadVideoCall()
}

private fun loadVideoCall() {
    val filePath = "file:android_asset/call.html"
    webView.loadUrl(filePath)

    webView.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            if (first) {
                callJavascriptFunction("javascript:init(\"${cUID}\")")

                if (type == 1 && first) {
                    RDB.child("Users")
                        .child(qUID!!)
                        .child("incoming")
                        .setValue(cUID)
                }

                first = false
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun listenForConnId() {
    if (type == 0) {
            RDB.child("Users").child(cUID).child("incoming")
                .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.value != null && isPeerConnected) {
                            callJavascriptFunction("javascript:startCall(\"${snapshot.value.toString()}\")")
                        } else {
                            finish()
                        }
                    }
                })
    }
    if (type == 1) {
        RDB.child("Users").child(qUID!!).child("incoming")
            .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.value != null && isPeerConnected) {
                        callJavascriptFunction("javascript:listen()")
                    }
                    if (snapshot.value == null) {
                        finish()
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}

private fun callJavascriptFunction(functionString: String) {
    webView.post { webView.evaluateJavascript(functionString, null) }
}
```

//javascript call.js//

```
let localVideo = document.getElementById("local-video")
let remoteVideo = document.getElementById("remote-video")

localVideo.style.opacity = 0
remoteVideo.style.opacity = 0

localVideo.onplaying = () => { localVideo.style.opacity = 1 }
remoteVideo.onplaying = () => { remoteVideo.style.opacity = 1 }

let peer
function init(userId) {
//    peer = new Peer(userId) **<<<get same result with default method**

    peer = new Peer(userId, { 'iceServers': [
            { 'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
            { url: 'turn:homeo@turn.bistri.com:80', credential: 'homeo' },
            {
                url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
                credential: 'muazkh',
                username: 'webrtc@live.com'
            },
            {
                url: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
                credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
                username: '28224511:1379330808'
            },
            {
                url: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
                credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
                username: '28224511:1379330808'
            },
            {
                url: 'turn:turn.bistri.com:80',
                credential: 'homeo',
                username: 'homeo'
            },
            {
                url: 'turn:turn.anyfirewall.com:443?transport=tcp',
                credential: 'webrtc',
                username: 'webrtc'
            }
        ], 'sdpSemantics': 'unified-plan'
    })

    peer.on('open', () => {
        Android.onPeerConnected()

        navigator.getUserMedia({
            audio: true, 
            video: true
        }, (stream) => {
            localVideo.srcObject = stream
            localStream = stream
            localVideo.className = "secondary-video"
        }, (err) => {
            console.error('PeerJS > Failed : peer.on open > navigator.getUserMedia', err);
        })

    }, (err) => {
        console.error('PeerJS > Failed : peer.on open', err);
    })

    peer.on('error', function(err) {
        console.error('PeerJS > error : function(err)', err);
    });
}

let localStream
function listen() {
    peer.on('call', (call) => {

        navigator.getUserMedia({
            audio: true, 
            video: true
        }, (stream) => {
            localVideo.srcObject = stream
            localStream = stream

            call.answer(stream)
            call.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
                remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream

                remoteVideo.className = "primary-video"
                localVideo.className = "secondary-video"

            }, (err) => {
                console.error('PeerJS > Failed : peer.on call > call.on stream', err);
            })

        }, (err) => {
            console.error('PeerJS > Failed : peer.on call > navigator.getUserMedia', err);
        })

    }, (err) => {
        console.error('PeerJS > Failed : peer.on call', err);
    })
}

function startCall(otherUserId) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true
    }, (stream) => {

        localVideo.srcObject = stream
        localStream = stream

        const call = peer.call(otherUserId, stream)
        call.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
            remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream

            remoteVideo.className = "primary-video"
            localVideo.className = "secondary-video"

        }, (err) => {
            console.error('PeerJS > Failed : startCall > navigator.getUserMedia > call.on stream', err);
        })

    }, (err) => {
        console.error('PeerJS > Failed : startCall > navigator.getUserMedia', err);
    })
}

function toggleVideo(b) {
    if (b == "true") {
        localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = true
    } else {
        localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false
    }
} 

function toggleAudio(b) {
    if (b == "true") {
        localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = true
    } else {
        localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false
    }
}

function getUserID() {
    return peer.id
}

function disconnect() {
    peer.disconnect()
    peer.destroy()
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: When 2 peer connected. remote stream not working with no error or any log.

Comment: have you solved this issue? I am also creating the same function as this but I have a problem with the camera change function. I don't know how can I do this in the ongoing call? same like sometimes works on both side sometimes don't